# App is running in simulator but not on Apple Watch

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, watchkit, apple-watch

I'm trying to run a basic hello world watch app with an image. It is running fine in simulator but when I choose the iOS Device + Watch Device, app is taking time to load forever and not showing anything. I tried restarting phone/watch but nothing showed up.

Comment: Are app groups enabled and configured?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a familiar watchOS bug for me. :)

You should try to delete the watch app from your watch using the Watch app on your phone, then run it again. If it still loads infinitely, go to the watch's home screen and open it manually again.